# needed python packages for ipython

Tags: ipython

I have recently installed ipython and have before that installed curses:

jinja2 numpy pexpect pygments qt sqlite3 tornado zmq

I have run iptest just after and got OK at the end. But near the end of the report there was the following:

Tools and libraries NOT available at test time:
   azure cython matplotlib oct2py pymongo rpy2 wx wx.aui

My question is whether those listed as not available at test time need to be installed for ipython to run optimally?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Question have already been asked and answerd on ML by other users :

http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/IPython-User-question-about-need-td5006172.html

Here is the answer given by MinRK:

> No, but some tests of compatibility or extensions, etc. use those, so it's just a note to tell which tests were run.